# Not able to use string length function in abs function c++

Tags: c++

```
void f(const string& a,const string& b){
    // works
    int lena = a.length();
    int lenb = b.length();
    return abs(lena-lenb);

    // does not work
    return abs(a.length()-b.length());
}
```

I'm in a little confusion I'm not able call string `length()` function in `abs()` function. When I put the result of string `length()` function in an integer data type there is no error.

The error is this when I call string `length()` function inside `abs()`.

```
error: call of overloaded 
    abs(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type) is ambiguous
    abs(a.length()-b.length);
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings, it could have told you a thing or two. Also, read about unsigned arithmetic and check the documentation what `string::length()` actually returns. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
a.length()-b.length()
```

The result ends up having type `std::size_t` because the return type of `std::string::length()` is `std::size_t` too.

When you call `std::abs` with such a type, the compiler has to choose one of the following overloads:

```
int           abs(int n);
long          abs(long n);
long long     abs(long long n);
std::intmax_t abs(std::intmax_t n);
```

And there is no rule in the language that promotes/converts an unsigned integer to a specific signed one here, which means the compiler cannot choose for you.

However, when you call it with:

```
lena-lenb
```

That has type `int` since it is the subtraction of two `int`s, so the following overload is chosen:

```
int           abs(int n);
```

Comment: That's true! This error can be resolved by typecasting the value to int `return abs(int(a.length()-b.length()));` This should work!!

Comment: Better to always subtract the smaller from the larger.